# Discord.js and PostgreSQL row hbucks is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, discord.js

DUPLICATE POST: This is due to the fact that I accidentally deleted my account... Don't ask why. I just did lol. I apologize for it being a duplicate post but I don't have access to that post anymore.

I recently just switched over from MySQL to PostgreSQL in terms of Databases for my new Discord.js bot. I keep getting an the error saying that rows hbucks is undefined or not defined. The code is below.

```
let mysql = require("pg");
function generateXp(){
  let min = 1;
  let max = 3;
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}



module.exports = (bot, message, args, con) => {
  con.query(`SELECT * FROM hbucks WHERE id = ${message.author.id} AND guildid = ${message.guild.id}`, (err, rows) => { //Where id defines what row to use, this is stating that you are going to organize it by the id
    if(err) throw err;

    let sql;
    let username = message.author.username
    let authorid = message.author.id
    if(rows.length < 1) {
      sql = `INSERT INTO hbucks (id, username, guildid, hbucks) VALUES (${message.author.id}, '${username}', ${message.guild.id}, ${generateXp()})`
      con.query(sql);
    } else {




      let hBucks = rows.fields[0].hbucks;



      sql = `UPDATE hbucks SET hbucks = ${hBucks + generateXp()} WHERE id = ${authorid} AND guildid = ${message.guild.id}`;
      con.query(sql, console.log);
      sql = `UPDATE hbucks SET username = '${username}' WHERE id = ${authorid} AND guildid = ${message.guild.id}`;
      con.query(sql, console.log);

    }


}
);



}
```

And the error is let hBucks = rows[0].hbucks is undefined. This code seemed to work and have no issues at all with MySQL

Comment: What's the value of `rows[0]`?

Comment: @dustytrash It is undefined. I can't get a value of it. It just says it is rows: [object Object]

Comment: What's the result if you add `console.log(JSON.stringify(rows)); console.log(rows);` inside the con.query?

Comment: @dustytrash https://ghostbin.com/paste/9pdae

Comment: Please post the error stack.

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
// Assuming you want the whole object.
let hBucks = rows.fields[0];
```

Here's the rows.fields[0] object:

```
{name: "id", tableID: 16395, columnID: 5, dataTypeID: 20, dataTypeSize: 8, …}
```

You can access its fields like this:

```
var id= rows.fields[0].name;
var tableId = rows.fields[0].tableID;
var columnID = rows.fields[0].columnID;
// ....
```

Comment: Well it worked, and it didn't. Now I get this error saying that column "nan" is undefined or something. https://hastebin.com/wuqiwowupo.coffeescript

Comment: @VincentLauro Which line do you get that error? NaN means "not a number"

Comment: @VincentLauro at line 31&18 I noticed you have quotes around `'${username}'`

Comment: Now it says that column "nan" does not exist, along with errors of inserting with the username. To prevent Stack Overflow warning me with the comments, if you have Discord, can we chat on there. My name is Vincent Lauro#1067

Comment: Sorry, but also, I have been doing let hBucks = rows.fields[0].hbucks, but in the example you are doing .name, .tableID, and columnID, but how does it know what column to choose from?